# How to hide space of UITableViewCellReorderControl in UITableViewCell?

Tags: swift, uitableview, ios9

This is what I do when cell is gonna be displayed:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if let reorderControl = cell.huntedSubviewWithClassName("UITableViewCellReorderControl") {

        let resizedReorderControl = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetMaxX(reorderControl.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(reorderControl.frame)))

        resizedReorderControl.addSubview(reorderControl)
        cell.addSubview(resizedReorderControl)

        let sizeDifference = CGSizeMake(resizedReorderControl.frame.size.width - reorderControl.frame.size.width, resizedReorderControl.frame.size.height - reorderControl.frame.size.height)
        let transformRatio = CGSizeMake(resizedReorderControl.frame.size.width / reorderControl.frame.size.width, resizedReorderControl.frame.size.height / reorderControl.frame.size.height)

        var transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity

        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, transformRatio.width, transformRatio.height)
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, -sizeDifference.width / 2, -sizeDifference.height / 2)

        resizedReorderControl.transform = transform
    }
}
```

Simple get reorder view and transform this to make it able reorder cell tapping on a whole cell. But there was left a space after moving reorder control to different subview.

The cell just displayed:

[image]

The cell while moving:

[image]

The cell should look like this (be able to reorder without space for reorder control):

[image]

**What do I mean?**

My idea was to reorder the `UITableViewCell` by tapping any place on it (*not only by tapping triple lines on the right side*). Then I get these `UIView` and spread this all over the cell. But some problem arised. The space of triple lines left empty. What to do to remove that space?

Comment: Can't understand what you are looking for. But I think you are talking about [tableView:shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:)

Comment: I updated the question. Please, have a look.

Comment: AFAIK UITableViewCellReorderControl is not a public class, your app might be rejected for that. I'd suggest to add a long tap gesture recognizer, take the cell snapshot, add a subview emulating the cell and modify datasource as needed while this view is being moved around. Not as easy to implement but you get almost a full control on how it looks.

Comment: Really? Is it forbidden? Hence, how could I reorder the cell by tapping on a whole cell, and without showing reorder control. Is it possible? You can post your reply as an answer. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend accessing a private class (UITableViewCellReorderControl) as Apple discourages it. On top of that, they have all the right to make any modifications around this property whenever they need.
But if you still need to remove the empty space on the right after adding the above code you have posted already, just add this code to your UITableViewCell subclass:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    contentView.frame.size.width = frame.size.width
}
```

Its just a workaround by the way.